# How can i display image from database?

Tags: php, mysql

Image can't display from database in php and it's fire such error.
When I execute this code such error is occure The image cannot be display beacuse it's contain error. Image is store in mysql database and field type is BLOB. IT didn't find any solution to avoid this error.

```
<?php
require_once('database/db.class.php');
$objDatabase=new db_class();
$objDatabase->connect();
$sql="SELECT id,firstname,lastname,sex,email,userimage,ext,city,state,username FROM t_users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
$totalRow=$objDatabase->select($sql);
if($row=$objDatabase->get_row($totalRow, 'MYSQL_BOTH'))
    {
        $userArray=array('id'=>$row['id'],'firstname'=>$row['firstname'],'lastname'=>$row['lastname'],'sex'=>$row['sex'],'email'=>$row['email'],'userimage'=>$row['userimage'],'ext'=>$row['ext'],'city'=>$row['city'],'state'=>$row['state'],'username'=>$row['username']);
    }

?>


  <table cellspacing="10px" width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td width="23%" style="vertical-align:top">
  <?php
    header("Content-type: image/{$userArray['ext']}");
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($userArray['userimage']));
    echo  $userArray['userimage'];
  ?>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Upload Image Code

```
@list(, , $imtype, ) = getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
    // Get image type.
    // We use @ to omit errors

if ($imtype == 3) // cheking image type
$ext="png";   // to use it later in HTTP headers
elseif ($imtype == 2)
$ext="jpeg";
elseif ($imtype == 1)
    $ext="gif";
else
$msg = 'Error: unknown file format';

   $img = file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
$img = mysql_real_escape_string($img);
        // Preparing data to be used in MySQL query

$data=array('firstname'=>$_REQUEST['firstname'],'lastname'=>$_REQUEST['lastname'],'sex'=>$_REQUEST['gender'],'email'=>$_REQUEST['email'],'userimage'=>$img,'ext'=>$ext,'city'=>$_REQUEST['city'],'state'=>$_REQUEST['state'],'zipcode'=>$_REQUEST['zipcode'],'username'=>$_REQUEST['usernameText'],'password'=>$_REQUEST['passwordText']);
$result=$objDatabase->insert_array('t_users',$data);    


 <input name="photo" type="file" id="photo">
```

Comment: Please shorten your shared code to contain only what is related to the question.

Comment: Can you show us showimage.php?  That's where the problem is, yes?

Comment: How is userImage stored in your database?

Comment: Have you checked the database to see if the image data is being stored correctly? Try `select md5(userimage) from t_users where ...` and see if it matches md5sum of the file you uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this isn't the way to do it, just store the image as per usual, then store the path in the database.

If you do want to do it this way, you'll need to make a new file, called something like image.php, then put

```
<?php

require_once('database/db.class.php');

$objDatabase=new db_class();
$objDatabase->connect();
$sql="SELECT id,firstname,lastname,sex,email,userimage,ext,city,state,username FROM t_users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
$totalRow=$objDatabase->select($sql);

if($row=$objDatabase->get_row($totalRow, 'MYSQL_BOTH'))
{
    $userArray=array('id'=>$row['id'],'firstname'=>$row['firstname'],'lastname'=>$row['lastname'],'sex'=>$row['sex'],'email'=>$row['email'],'userimage'=>$row['userimage'],'ext'=>$row['ext'],'city'=>$row['city'],'state'=>$row['state'],'username'=>$row['username']);
}

header("Content-type: image/{$userArray['ext']}");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($userArray['userimage']));
echo  $userArray['userimage'];
?>
```

in to that file.

Then in the table use

```
<img src='/image.php ?>' alt='' />
```

But don't, just do it by storing the path in the DB, it's rare that you should be storing binary data in a database that's not the file system, for reasons I won't go into here.

Comment: One reason to store in the database is if you have a webserver cluster. The database is a common data store for all of them, unless you also implement automatic replication of files.

Answer (score 1):

**edit** - I forgot to include: base64 files will be considerably larger than BLOB.

---

Try saving it as base64 instead of BLOB.

Here is a function I found on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

```
function base64_encode_image ($filename=string,$filetype=string) {
    if ($filename) {
        $imgbinary = fread(fopen($filename, "r"), filesize($filename));
        return 'data:image/' . $filetype . ';base64,' . base64_encode($imgbinary);
    }
}
```

When you retrieve the image from the database, it will be as a base64 string, you can put the string directly into the src="" attribute in your HTML (no need to decode). Browsers can parse base64 and display an image.

Comment: Be aware that data uris don't work in IE 7 and lower. Also that they won't be cached across pages, and that they won't be downloading in parallel in the way a normal image would be. In short, though you can do this, it's very rarely the right way to do it.

Comment: PHP has simple base64_encode() and base64_decode() functions available, so you can turn it back to a binary file on the server side if need be.  But I must agree with Rich, it is a somewhat sloppy way of doing it.